# how can I stop re-initiate counter

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
   var time=0;
   var i=0;
   
   function stopwatch(){
       document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=i;
       i++; }
       
  
  
   function start(){
      time=window.setInterval('stopwatch()',500);
   }

    function stop(){
       window.clearInterval(time);
   }
  </script>

<p id="p1">0</p>
<button onclick="start()">Start counter</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop counter</button>
```

I'm trying to build a stopwatch but if I click the start button more than once
the times go faster and faster whenever I click the 'start button' and the 'stop' button doesn't work
How can I fix this Issue

Comment: This is because the id gets changed of setInterval. So when you pass the "time"  to the clearInterval , it does not stop. Better you can do one thing disable the start button once clicked and enable it when you click Stop

Comment: Call `stop()` first inside `start()` before setting a new one.

Comment: Or you need to have a flag `started = false` and in `start()` you check `if (!started) time = ...; started = true;` and in `stop()` `started = false;` This kind of logic can you help pause and resume as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  var time=0;
  var i=0;

  function stopwatch(){
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=i;
  i++; }


  function start(){
    if(time) return;
    time=window.setInterval('stopwatch()',500);
  }

  function stop(){
    window.clearInterval(time);
    time = null;
  }
```

```html
<p id="p1">0</p>
<button onclick="start()">Start counter</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop counter</button>
```

Comment: dose 'time' became bigger than 0 when the code window.setInterval('stopwatch()',500); get initiated?

Comment: In your case `time` is not a count, it's object, it's storing interval instance. this is simple if `time` variable is having something it's returning back

Comment: `time` is a numeric id. It is not an object and does not store the interval instance. Just the key to it. Strictly writing, it actually is a count of id.

Comment: Thanks @Lain, Got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button when onStart and enable it on stop

```js
var time=0;
var i=0;
var start_btn = document.getElementById("start")

 function stopwatch(){
     document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = i;
     i++; 
 }


 function start(){
    time = window.setInterval(() => stopwatch(),500);
    start_btn.disabled = true;
 }

  function stop(){
     window.clearInterval(time);
     start_btn.disabled = false;
 }
```

```html
<p id="p1">0</p>
<button id="start" onclick="start()">Start counter</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop counter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of a flag and handle this. But disabling buttons is a good UX behavior. You can combine both as below.

```js
 var time=0;
 var i=0;
 var started = false;
 
   function stopwatch(){
      document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=i;
      i++; 
    }
  
   function start(){
      if(!started){
          started = true;
          updateButtons();
          time=window.setInterval('stopwatch()',500);
      }
   }

    function stop(){
        started = false;
        updateButtons();
       window.clearInterval(time);
   }
   function updateButtons(){
        document.getElementById("startbtn").disabled = started
        document.getElementById("stopbtn").disabled = !started
   }
```

```html
<p id="p1">0</p>
<button id="startbtn" onclick="start()">Start counter</button>
<button id="stopbtn" onclick="stop()">Stop counter</button>
```